# How to properly send and receive XML using curl?

Tags: php, xml, http, post, curl

I've been trying to post XML and get response from the server but with no luck.

Here are the conditions on server side:

- Requests to the server should be sent as XML over HTTP 1.1.

The following requirements apply to the HTTP request:

- The request type should be POST;
- A `Content-Length` header should be present, and the total length of the request should be below 16KB;
- A `Content-Type` header should be present, containing the media type value `text/xml`;

Here is my script:

```
$url = "http://somedomain.com";
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request PartnerID="asasdsadsa" Type="TrackSearch"> <TrackSearch> <Title>love</Title>    <Tags> <MainGenre>Blues</MainGenre> </Tags> <Page Number="1" Size="20"/> </TrackSearch> </Request>';
$header  = "POST HTTP/1.1 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/xml \r\n";
$header .= "Content-length: ".strlen($xml)." \r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n"; 
$header .= $xml;
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $data;
if(curl_errno($ch))
    print curl_error($ch);
else
    curl_close($ch);
```

This gives me:

```
 HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.
 Bad Request - Invalid URL
```

Comment: Do you have access to the somedomain.com's server logs? It's hard to say what the 400 is actually trying to say..

Comment: You may want to try to posting the XML to a script on your own server and ensure that the data being received is what you expect.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Does this help?

```
<?php
$url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Request PartnerID="asasdsadsa" Type="TrackSearch"> <TrackSearch> <Title>love</Title>    <Tags> <MainGenre>Blues</MainGenre> </Tags> <Page Number="1" Size="20"/> </TrackSearch> </Request>';

$headers = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml",
    "Content-length: " . strlen($xml),
    "Connection: close",
);

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $data;
if(curl_errno($ch))
    print curl_error($ch);
else
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://www.php.net/curl_setopt).

> CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST
>
> A custom request method to use instead of "GET"
> or "HEAD" when doing a HTTP request. This is useful for doing "DELETE"
> or other, more obscure HTTP requests. Valid values are things like
> "GET", "POST", "CONNECT" and so on; i.e. Do not enter a whole HTTP
> request line here. For instance, entering "GET /index.html
> HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" would be incorrect.

The parameter for `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` should be simply `POST` and you can use `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to set headers.

Comment: Or as @James mentions, you can more concisely use `CURLOPT_POST`.